# PHP mail() not working (another one)

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm currently trying to use the php mail() function, I've looked up a lot and can't make it work. Here is the code:

```
$name=$_POST[name];

if(mail("me@mydomain.com","test"," Name: $name", "FROM: me@otherdomain.com")){
    echo "Your message was succefully sent!";
}
else{
    echo "Your message was NOT succefully sent!";

}
```

Whenever I try to run the script, which I'm running on my personal Mac, I get the "Your message was seccefully sent!", however, checking the e-mail, it's not there, not even in the spam box.
Searching around I already made the necesseary config at php.ini.default:

```
sendmail_from = "sendmail -t -i"
```

Also made some changes at the /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = mydomain.com
```

I'm running on Snow Leopard and right now I have NO clue with what's wrong here. I've been into this for a while.
Thanks in advance

PS: sorry if I did something wrong with the question, new on stackoverflow

Comment: You need a mail server to run it locally

Comment: It wouldn't run locally. not unless like @Paul have said, you need a mail server for that.

Comment: no need to change anything, your mail function is working fine for me as i tested it on my websever, but for local as paul said you need a mail server.